# Java Web Start and Web-proxy caching

Tags: caching, proxy, java-web-start, jnlp, webproxy

I have a Rich Internet Application which is provided in the SaaS schema (cloud) via Internet. The application is deployed via Java Web Start: users click on a link pointing to a JNLP file to the provider site (http://somesite.com/myapp/myapp.jnlp); then the application is downloaded and locally cached (from the client's Java control panel I see that the application is about 40 MB). I expect that if no server-side changes occur the clients use the cached version.
A possible issue can happen when a new server version is released: all clients (hundreds) can potentially download the new version at the same time.
To prevent this problem I would like  to explore the possibility of using the Web proxy as a cache: the first client downloads from the Internet the new version, other clients download the version cached on the Web proxy.
Is this feasible? I have some doubts mostly due to the fact that, from the Java control panel --> Java cache viewer (Java 6 on Win XP) I can see 1 application (40 MB) in the 'application view', some JARs when I switch to 'Resources view', but when I go to the disk location supposed to physically host the cache I see a lot of folders (most empty) and .idx files (no trace of JARs).
The idea is to tell the Web proxy (which is Forefront TMG) to cache only a set of files (which ones? which extensions?) coming from the provider's site.
I attach the cleansed version ofthe JNLP file with the caching option, but I guess they are not relevant to my question since they only deal of the caching option on the CLIENT (right?)

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://somesite.com/myapp/" href="http://somesite.com/myapp/WebStart.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>....</title>
    <vendor>....</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://somesite.com"/>
    <description>....</description>
    <icon href="http://....gif" kind="default"/>
    <shortcut online="true" install="false">
      <desktop/>
      <menu submenu="...."/>
    </shortcut>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <update check="timeout" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
    <java initial-heap-size="20971520" max-heap-size="536870912" java-vm-args="-XX:MaxPermSize=128m" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.6.0_11+"/>
    <jar href="http://......jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
     ... some other JARs...
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="com.package.....">
    <argument>-showSavePwd</argument>
    <argument>-forcedHttpsLoginPort:443</argument>
    <argument>-availableLanguages:en;fr;de;es;ja</argument>
    <argument>-forceCountryByLanguage:false</argument>
  </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've used the CloudFront for our CDN and it has worked well for almost 2 years (20+ application updates).  I would adjust your JNLP like this:

```
 ...
  <resources>
    <java initial-heap-size="20971520" max-heap-size="536870912" java-vm-args="-XX:MaxPermSize=128m" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.6.0_11+"/>
    <jar href="http://xyz.cloudfront.net/path/some.jar" download="eager" main="false" version="123"/>
     ... some other JARs...
  </resources>
...
```

http://xyz.cloudfront.net/ is configured with the origin pointing to http://somesite.com/.

After that CloudFront is configured to cache query strings which allows the version mechanism to work.  After this initial configuration I've not had to do anything to keep it running.